# Identity about Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

If I note $(F_N)_N = \{0,1,1,2,3,5,...\}$ the Fibonacci sequence, I have proved the identity
$$ \forall N \geqslant 0,\,F_{N}^2 = F_{N} + 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{N-3} F_{k+1}\,F_{k+2}\,F_{N-k-2}. $$

This relation can be obtained by induction and by using the equality 
$$F_{n+2}^2 =(F_{n+1}+F_n)^2=F^2_{n+1}+F^2_n+2F_{n+1}F_n.$$

Indeed we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{n+2}^2 &=& F^2_{n+1}+F^2_n+2F_{n+1}F_n \\
\\
&=& F_{n+1} + 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} F_{k+1}\,F_{k+2}\,F_{n-k-1} + F_{n} + 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} F_{k+1}\,F_{k+2}\,F_{n-k-2} +  2\,F_{n+1}F_n  \\
\\
&=& F_{n+2} + 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} F_{k+1}\,F_{k+2}\,F_{n-k} + 2\,F_{n-1}F_n + 2\,F_{n+1}F_n \\
\\
&=& F_{n+2} + 2\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} F_{k+1}\,F_{k+2}\,F_{n-k}.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Question :** I would like to know if anyone had ever seen a similar equality please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see your proof.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how you found it. Looks like something American Mathematical Monthly might like to publish in their Elementary Problems section.

Comment: It's remarkably similar to some of the identities in [SUMS OF CERTAIN PRODUCTS OF FIBONACCI AND LUCAS NUMBERS](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/37-3/melham2.pdf) by R. S. Mellam (particularly theorem 4.1). I haven't found whether it's been published before but I'd guess that it's a special case of another identity.

Comment: Finding (the "form" of) this identity has been harder than proving by induction

Answer (score 1):

Define, for $n\ge3$, $\displaystyle S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-2}$. Then, the focus of your identity, $S_n=\frac{F_n^2-F_n}{2}$, is really on $S_n$ since the other terms are simpler.

Searching for the first few values of $S_n$ in the OEIS gives gives us sequence [A191797](https://oeis.org/A191797), i.e. $S_n=\binom{F_n}{2}=\frac{2F_n^2-F_{n+4}+3F_{n+1}}{4}=T_{F_{n}-1}=\frac{F_n(F_n-1)}{2}$, where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient and $T_n$ is the $n$th triangular number. This shows half your identity.

This should give you more places to look to see if the identity has been previously published. I've not found any reference to the sum of products formula, so it may be original.

---

We may prove the identity as follows

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
S_n-S_{n-1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-1-k-2}
\\
&=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}F_1+F_{n-3}F_{n-2}F_{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-5}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-2}\ldots
\\&\quad\ldots-\left(F_{n-3}F_{n-2}F_{1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-5}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-3}\right)
\\
&=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+\cancel{F_{n-3}F_{n-2}-F_{n-3}F_{n-2}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-5}\left(F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-2}-F_{k+1}F_{k+2}F_{n-k-3}\right)
\\
&=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-5}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}\left[\underbrace{F_{n-k-2}}_{F_{n-k-3}+F_{n-k-4}}-F_{n-k-3}\right]
\\
&=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{(n-2)-3}F_{k+1}F_{k+2}\left(F_{(n-2)-k-2}\right)
\\
&=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+S_{n-2}
\end{align}
$$

With $S_3=F_1F_2F_{3-0-2}=1$ and $S_4=F_1F_2F_{4-0-2}+F_2F_3F_{4-1-2}=3$, this recurrence relation gives us an alternate definition for $S_n$. Therefore, the aim is to inductively prove that, for $n\ge 3$, $S_n=\frac{F_n(F_n-1)}{2}$. For the two base cases, $S_3=1=\frac{F_3(F_3-1)}{2}$ and $S_4=3=\frac{F_4(F_4-1)}{2}$. Then, assuming $S_k=\frac{F_k(F_k-1)}{2}$ and $S_{k+1}=\frac{F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}-1)}{2}$, we have

$$\begin{align}S_{k+2}
&=F_{k}F_{k+1}+S_{k}+S_{k+1}
\\
&=F_{k}F_{k+1}+\frac{F_k(F_k-1)}{2}+\frac{F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}-1)}{2}
\\
&=\frac12\left(2F_{k}F_{k+1}+{F_k^2-F_k}+{F_{k+1}^2-F_{k+1}}\right)
\\
&=\frac12\left(2F_{k}F_{k+1}+\left[F_{k-1}F_{k+1}-(-1)^k\right]+\left[F_{k}F_{k+2}-(-1)^{k+1}\right]-F_{k+2}\right)\tag{*}
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{k+1}\left(2F_{k}+F_{k-1}\right)+F_{k}F_{k+2}-F_{k+2}\right)
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{k+1}\left(F_{k}+F_{k+1}\right)+F_{k}F_{k+2}-F_{k+2}\right)
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{k+1}F_{k+2}+F_{k}F_{k+2}-F_{k+2}\right)
\\
&=\frac{F_{k+2}(F_{k+2}-1)}{2}
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof. $(*)$ uses Cassini's identity, $F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n$.

Comment: The identity can be easily shown by induction like I said in my question, since I have proved MYSELF this relation ...

Comment: @Kermatoni Yes, and you neglected to show your proof, even after we asked. So, in providing another one, I've given various equations which could be used to find published identities, e.g. $S_n-S_{n-1}=F_{n-2}F_{n-1}+S_{n-2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that what I had written in the question was enough to prove it easily :)   The new definition/equation of S_n that you have found is the starting point of my more general result :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)